# Unrecognized VM option 'DumpPerfMapAtExit' when running clojure program on eclipse-temurin:17.0.9

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

I've below clojure code -

```clj
(ns profiler.async.profiler-demo
  (:require [clj-async-profiler.core :as profiler]
            [clj-async-profiler.ui :as profiler.ui]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (System/getProperty "java.version"))
  (profiler/serve-ui 8094)
  (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. ^Runnable profiler.ui/stop-server)))
```

When I run the program it is running fine.

```bash
/Users/rnatarajan/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.9-tem/bin/java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-G1UseAdaptiveIHOP -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=85 -XX:+PreserveFramePointer -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59952:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/demo-clj/src:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.11.1/clojure-1.11.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/xforms/0.19.4/xforms-0.19.4.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/traversy/traversy/0.5.0/traversy-0.5.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.analyzer/1.1.0/tools.analyzer-1.1.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.analyzer.jvm/1.2.2/tools.analyzer.jvm-1.2.2.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-async-profiler/1.1.1/clj-async-profiler-1.1.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/macrovich/0.2.1/macrovich-0.2.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/1.3.6/tools.reader-1.3.6.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.memoize/1.0.253/core.memoize-1.0.253.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.priority-map/1.1.0/data.priority-map-1.1.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.cache/1.0.225/core.cache-1.0.225.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.async/1.6.673/core.async-1.6.673.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar clojure.main -m profiler.async.profiler-demo
17.0.9
Starting server on port 8094

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Now the issue is I've to profile my application. I'm following this [example](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/04/07/how-to-use-perf-to-monitor-java-performance/). I add the  `-XX:+DumpPerfMapAtExit` JVM arg I get error

The error is -

```bash
/Users/rnatarajan/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.9-tem/bin/java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-G1UseAdaptiveIHOP -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=85 -XX:+PreserveFramePointer -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints  -XX:+DumpPerfMapAtExit -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59952:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/demo-clj/src:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.11.1/clojure-1.11.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/xforms/0.19.4/xforms-0.19.4.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/traversy/traversy/0.5.0/traversy-0.5.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.analyzer/1.1.0/tools.analyzer-1.1.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.analyzer.jvm/1.2.2/tools.analyzer.jvm-1.2.2.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-async-profiler/1.1.1/clj-async-profiler-1.1.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/macrovich/0.2.1/macrovich-0.2.1.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.reader/1.3.6/tools.reader-1.3.6.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.memoize/1.0.253/core.memoize-1.0.253.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.priority-map/1.1.0/data.priority-map-1.1.0.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.cache/1.0.225/core.cache-1.0.225.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.async/1.6.673/core.async-1.6.673.jar:/Users/rnatarajan/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar clojure.main -m profiler.async.profiler-demo
Unrecognized VM option 'DumpPerfMapAtExit'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my run configuration in intellij idea -

[image: run configuration]

Comment: (1) It's not a Clojure issue if you can't even get the JVM to start; (2) Are you using the same JVM as the one used in the text you're copying from? `-XX` options are pretty implementation-specific, I think, and I wouldn't be shocked if another implementation doesn't support everything the Oracle OpenJDK does.